# What are the best pdf annotation tools in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, pdf

I am considering transferring from Windows to Xubuntu. When using Windows, I always use Foxit reader to do annotation. I am wondering are there any alternatives in Xubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Foxit reader has a version for Gnu/Linux.

Comment: @kyodake But I am not able to install it successfully on my laptop. Are there any tricks in installation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good Foxit reader equivalent (or other PDF editor)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/12401/what-is-a-good-foxit-reader-equivalent-or-other-pdf-editor)

Comment: There are several options, if they do not work, can you explain what you tried and why it did not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make annotations on .PDF files like on Okular, but without using Okular? What .PDF viewer should I use?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180490/how-to-make-annotations-on-pdf-files-like-on-okular-but-without-using-okular)

Answer (score 0):

evince can do annotations but unfortunately only Ubuntu 15.04 contains version 3.16 that can also remove annotations.

Answer (score 0):

PDF Studio is cross-platform (run on Java) but commercial. Check out their website: https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/

I've seen similar functionality in Adobe Acrobat (it seems to allow the same kind of highlights).
Foxit is another good one, now on Linux.